# Can you die from falling in Hogwarts Legacy?

Tags: hogwarts-legacy

I noticed that you can take damage if you fall or jump from a high enough place, but can you actually die if you go even higher and fall or jump off?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yes**.

You can die from falling or jumping off a very high place. People are also discussing this on [Steam](https://steamcommunity.com/app/990080/discussions/0/3806154368652364135/) and many have died.